# How to get the data sorted based on column values before comma

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In an unsorted large CSV file, How could i sort the `Resource Name` column so i can get all the same name results aligned sequentially lined up One after another like grep in my example below.

In the `Resource Name` column we need select the data before comma `,` in order to get it required result.

**My trial code:**

```
#!/home/uatacto/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd

cols = ['Status', 'Resource Name', 'Appliance',  'State',  'Description', 'Corrective Action']
df = pd.read_csv("ResourceAlertsReport.csv", usecols=cols)
#df['Resource Name'] = df['Resource Name'].str.lower()
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())

print(df)
```

**Resulted DataFrame Structure:**

```
        Status                                      Resource Name                     Appliance   State                                        Description                                  Corrective Action
0     critical                                     enc8005, bay 4                        ov8002  active  there are failed entries in the ilo integrated...  log into the ilo and view the integrated manag...
1     critical                                     enc8013, bay 9                        ov8004  active              the bios/hardware status is critical.  log into the ilo and view the integrated manag...
2     critical                                     enc8013, bay 9                        ov8004  locked  the ilo for the server hardware in bay 9 is re...  check the ilo system information - health summ...
3     critical                                            enc8002                        ov8001  locked  encountered connectivity problems with synergy...  refresh the enclosure, reseat the appliance, r...
4     critical                                    enc3061, bay 12                        ov3004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
5     critical                                            enc8002                        ov8001  locked  encountered connectivity problems with synergy...  refresh the enclosure, reseat the appliance, r...
6     critical                                     enc3070, bay 3                        ov3007  active  service event: the state of the processor in s...  a support ticket has been opened by the hpe su...
7     critical                                     enc2029, bay 3                        ov2002  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
8     critical                                     enc8058, bay 6                        ov8013  active  there are failed entries in the ilo integrated...  log into the ilo and view the integrated manag...
9     critical                                     enc8056, bay 8                        ov8013  active  there are failed entries in the ilo integrated...  log into the ilo and view the integrated manag...
10    critical                                     enc3054, bay 4                        ov3002  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
11    critical                                            enc8002                        ov8001  locked  encountered connectivity problems with synergy...  refresh the enclosure, reseat the appliance, r...
12    critical                                     enc8005, bay 4                        ov8002  locked  the product id and/or serial number of the ser...  if the server is running a workload, schedule ...
13    critical                                     enc1019, bay 1                        ov1001  active  the firmware integrity scan or boot time valid...  if configured for automatic recovery, the repa...
14    critical                                    enc8048, bay 11                        ov8010  active              the bios/hardware status is critical.  log into the ilo and view the integrated manag...
15    critical                                     enc8043, bay 5                        ov8008  active  service event: the physical status of a drive ...  a support ticket has been opened by the hpe su...
16    critical                                     enc8043, bay 5                        ov8008  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
17    critical                                    enc2009, bay 14         ov c7000 enclosures 1  active  there are failed entries in the ilo integrated...  log into the ilo and view the integrated manag...
18    critical                                     enc3054, bay 9                        ov3002  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
```

**Sorted result with grep:**

```
$ python test_ov.py | grep enc8013
1     critical                                     enc8013, bay 9                        ov8004  active              the bios/hardware status is critical.  log into the ilo and view the integrated manag...
2     critical                                     enc8013, bay 9                        ov8004  locked  the ilo for the server hardware in bay 9 is re...  check the ilo system information - health summ...
324   critical                                     enc8013, bay 3                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
389   critical                                    enc8013, bay 11                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
436   critical                                     enc8013, bay 8                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
491   critical                                     enc8013, bay 7                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
499   critical                                     enc8013, bay 5                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
643   critical                                     enc8013, bay 2                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
716   critical                                     enc8013, bay 1                        ov8004  locked            unable to discover the server hardware.  verify your request. if credentials were speci...
717   critical                                     enc8013, bay 1                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1197  critical                                     enc8013, bay 3                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1208  critical                                     enc8013, bay 5                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1266  critical                                     enc8013, bay 7                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1329  critical                                     enc8013, bay 2                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1362  critical                                    enc8013, bay 11                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1365  critical                                     enc8013, bay 1                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1502  critical                                     enc8013, bay 8                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1685  critical                                     enc8013, bay 2                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1723  critical                                     enc8013, bay 1                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
1735  critical                                     enc8013, bay 3                        ov8004  active  remote insight/ integrated lights-out self tes...  to decode the error-code look into cpqsm2cntlr...
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What if you try `df['Resource Name'] = df['Resource Name'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(','))))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two columns out of the `'Resource Name'` using the [`extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method with an regular expression and sort your values afterwards.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

t = """ Status   Resource Name
0     critical   enc8005, bay 4
1     critical   enc8013, bay 9
2     critical   enc8013, bay 9
3     critical   enc8002
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t), sep='\s\s+')

ans = df['Resource Name'].str.extract(r'(?P<a>\w+\d+)\,?\s*(?P<b>\w+\s+\d+)?') # this creates two columns 'a' and 'b'
df['a'] = ans['a']
df['b'] = ans['b']
df = df.sort_values(['a', 'b'])
>>> df
     Status   Resource Name        a       b
3  critical  enc8002         enc8002     NaN
0  critical  enc8005, bay 4  enc8005   bay 4
1  critical  enc8013, bay 9  enc8013   bay 9
2  critical  enc8013, bay 9  enc8013   bay 9
```

Comment: This throws error as some records don't have bay information. Example row indices 3, 5, 11.

Comment: @ mosc9575, thanks for answering however it fails with `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`  as there are not always comma aligned values in there.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, aligning names sequentially is sorting but what you did using grep is filtering/searching. Both are different tasks.

**For filtering (like you did with grep)**:

```
df = df[df['Resource Name'].str.contains('enc8013')]
```

Output:

```
    Status      Resource Name
1   critical    enc8013
2   critical    enc8013, bay 9
```

**For sorting by resource name:**

```
df['resource_name_only'] = df['Resource Name'].str.split(',').str[0]
df = df.sort_values(by=['resource_name_only'])
```

Output:

```
    Status      Resource Name       resource_name_only
0   critical    enc8005, bay 4      enc8005
1   critical    enc8013             enc8013
2   critical    enc8013, bay 9      enc8013
```

Comment: @ Krishnakanth Allika, what you said is right but i Just give an example that is what i am not looking for else it would so easy, thanks for answering though.

Comment: @kulfi, no worries. I updated my answer with sorting too. Next time, please make questions clearer to understand so that people can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with the following.

```
df["sort_column"] = df['Resource Name'].str.extract(r'(\S+)[,]|(\S+)', flags=0, expand=False).fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
df.sort_values('sort_column', inplace=True)
```